# Using an array to search active sheet

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have a worksheet which is updated regularly with details of duplicate records from a database.

I am trying to edit our current macro which searches for particular records however as I am new to Excel VBA I am struggling.

The macro works great however it only returns the cell reference for each ID number once. I am struggling to work out how to get it to return every cell reference for every time the specified ID number is listed.

The code I currently have is as follows (there are more ID numbers in the code but to save time I have removed these):

```
            Sub IDSearch()
'


Dim rg As Range
Dim lnglastrow As Long
Dim intnamemax As Integer
Dim strName() As String
Dim fnd As Boolean


intnamemax = 42

ReDim strName(1 To intnamemax)

strName(1) = "OR123456"
strName(2) = "C00123456"
strName(3) = "UK123456"


lnglastrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For I = 1 To intnamemax
    Set c = Range("j2:j" & lnglastrow).Find(strName(I), LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Proxy Candidate Found at " & c.Address
        fnd = True
    End If
Next I
If Not fnd Then
    MsgBox "No Proxy Candidates Found ", vbOKOnly, "Success!"
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the code below:

```
Sub IDSearch()
'


Dim rg As Range
Dim lnglastrow As Long
Dim intnamemax As Integer
Dim strName() As String
Dim fnd As Boolean    


intnamemax = 42

ReDim strName(1 To intnamemax)

strName(1) = "OR123456"
strName(2) = "C00123456"
strName(3) = "UK123456"


lnglastrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For I = 1 To intnamemax
    For J = 2 to lnglastrow
        'Set c = Range("j2:j" & lnglastrow).Find(strName(I), LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Instr(Range("J" & J).Value, strName(I)) > 0 Then
        'If Not c Is Nothing Then
            'MsgBox "Proxy Candidate Found at " & c.Address
            MsgBox "Proxy Candidate Found at " & "J" & J
            fnd = True
        'End If
    Next J
Next I

If Not fnd Then
    MsgBox "No Proxy Candidates Found ", vbOKOnly, "Success!"
End If

End Sub
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub IDSearch()

    Dim intnamemax As Integer
    intnamemax = 42

    Dim strName() As String
    ReDim strName(1 To intnamemax)

    strName(1) = "OR123456"
    strName(2) = "C00123456"
    strName(3) = "UK123456"

    Dim lnglastrow As Long
    lnglastrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Dim c As Range
    Dim fnd As Boolean

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To intnamemax
        Set c = Range("j2")
        Do While True
            If strName(i) = "" Then Exit Do
            Set c = c.Resize(lnglastrow).Offset(1).Find(strName(i), LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then
                Debug.Print strName(i); " found at " & c.Address
    '           MsgBox "Proxy Candidate Found at " & c.Address
                fnd = True
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    Next i

    If Not fnd Then
        MsgBox "No Proxy Candidates Found ", vbOKOnly, "Success!"
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Check out [`.FindNext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/range-findnext-method-excel). Something like this (havent tested it).

```
Dim f As Range
For I = 1 To intnamemax
    Set c = Range("j2:j" & lnglastrow).Find(strName(I), LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        f = c.Address
        MsgBox f
        Do
            Set c = c.FindNext(c)
            MsgBox c.Address
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> f
    End If
Next I
```